# Lights don't affect my textures while the game engine is running?

Tags: game-engine, light

When I'm making a level, the lights perfectly shade/brighten certain areas when the game engine isn't running, but when I run the game engine they don't affect anything at all!

I didn't have this problem with previous Blender Game Engine versions.
I'm using Blender 2.78a by the way if that helps you help me

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide more information? Add data about your scene and settings, current viewport mode, some screenshots of your scene, or possibly upload blend file

Comment: Is the lamp and are the objects in the same layer? Do you have GLSL or Multitexture mode?

Comment: Just the default loadout

Comment: What is the default loadout? It is easy to change and can therefore be different for everyone...